# Printing Names using Circular Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I was working on a circular linked list problem and solved it.But i got stuck in other problem. The program takes names of persons in circular linked list nodes and prints them.

My question is that program works fine if and only if the names are 4 characters or less.If the length of the names exceeds 4,it shows weird behaviour.

If the length of name is 5 characters,then the program is stuck on second iteration of the for loop of the initiate function.

If the length of name is 6 characters or more then program terminates immediately showing the names entered.

The source code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define NUM_PER_LINE 3

typedef struct node
{
 char name[SIZE];
 struct node * next;
} CListNode;

void get_name(char *a);
void print_list(CListNode *end_ptr);
CListNode *initiate(int n);
CListNode *insert_at_end(CListNode *first,CListNode *end_ptr, char *a);

int main(void) 
{
CListNode *list_end_ptr;

int n=6;
list_end_ptr=initiate(n);
print_list(list_end_ptr);

return 0;
}

void get_name(char *a)
{
 char *aa=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
 a=aa;
 scanf("%s", a);
}

CListNode *insert_at_end(CListNode *first,CListNode *end_ptr, char *a)
{
 CListNode *temp, *head=NULL;

 head=first;
 temp=(CListNode *) malloc(sizeof(CListNode));
 end_ptr->next=temp;
 strcpy(temp->name, a);
 temp->next=head;

 return temp;

}

CListNode *initiate(int n) 
{

 CListNode *end, *first=NULL,*ptr=NULL;
 int i;
 char new_name;
 end=(CListNode *) malloc(sizeof(CListNode));
 if (end==0) {
    printf("Allocation error...\n");
    exit(0); }
 end->next=end;

 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (i<1) {
        printf("Enter the name of the %d person: ", i+1);
        get_name(&new_name);
        strcpy(end->name, &new_name);
        first=end;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the %d person: ", i+1);
        get_name(&new_name);
        ptr=insert_at_end(first,end, &new_name);
        end=ptr;
    }
 }

 return end;
}

void print_list(CListNode *end_ptr)
{
 int i=1;
 CListNode *str_ptr;
 if (end_ptr == NULL)
    printf("\n List is empty");
 else
 {
    str_ptr = end_ptr->next;
    while (str_ptr !=  end_ptr)
    {
        printf("%s \t", str_ptr->name);
        str_ptr = str_ptr->next;
        if (i%NUM_PER_LINE==0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str_ptr->name);
 }
}
```

Comment: it cause undefined behavior due to overflow and you also have memory leak in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `get_name` function and the way you use it. Its signature assumes that the storage is already allocated, because you take a pointer, not a pointer to pointer. Your code ignores the allocation completely; on top of that, it passes a pointer to character.

Since you allocate `name` within the node, remove `malloc`, remove `new_name`, and pass `name` array to `get_name`:

```
void get_name(char *a) {
    scanf("%9s", a); // Limit the size to 9 chars
}
...
printf("Enter the name of the %d person: ", i+1);
get_name(end->name);
```